# Submodule of a flat module.

Tags: commutative-algebra, flatness

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity. Suppose that $A$ is a Noetherian regular ring with dimension equal to 1 and let $M$ be a flat $A$-module. Is it true that any sub-A-module of $M$ is flat?

Comment: Any torsion free module over a regular Noetherian domain of dimension one is flat.

Comment: [Here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AUW) is a reference for @Mohan statement.